# how to export cookies to txt file?

Tags: python, cookies

```
from COOKIESQ import ChromeCookieJar
jar = ChromeCookieJar()
jar.load()

jar.save("C:\ProgramData\cks.txt", ignore_discard=True)
```

***i get this error  i tried searching but i couldnt find anything.***

```
File "c:\Users\xxx\Desktop\c0OK13\cdemo.py", line 14, in <module>
    jar.save("C:\ProgramData\cokisqqq.txt", ignore_discard=True)   File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\cookiejar.py", line 1790, in save
    raise NotImplementedError() NotImplementedError
```

Answer (score 0):

What is `COOKIESQ` - where does that come from?

Evidently you are using an implementation of `ChromeCookieJar` which subclasses `FileCookieJar`, which if you look at line 1790 of `Python39\lib\http\cookiejar.py` will show you that `FileCookieJar` does not implement `save()`.

For example [this ChromeCookieJar implementation](https://github.com/taizan-hokuto/chrome_cookie/blob/master/chrome_cookie.py).

According to the [CookieJar documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.cookiejar.html), the `save()` method of class `FileCookieJar` "...raises NotImplementedError. Subclasses may leave this method unimplemented."

Therefore, your problem is that the implementation of `ChromeCookieJar` you are using does not implement the `save()` method.  But you knew that already from reading the error message.

If you want some guidance as to how to implement saving of cookies, look at the implementations of `save()` in the `LWPCookieJar` and `MozillaCookieJar` classes in `Python39\lib\http\cookiejar.py`.